# Sending a POST request to Microsoft Graph API

Tags: http, post, power-automate, ngrok, azure-bot-service

I'm having issues with one of my flows. I'm basically wanting to send a POST HTTP request to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls" so that it can automatically launch a Teams group call when an email enters a user's inbox. The bot is on Teams and I can call it/interact with it within Teams so I believe the issue lies with Power Automate. The flow starts running and continues to do so for about 10 minutes then fails with "Unknown Internal Server Error" with code 500. I've tried absolutely everything and have no idea where this is coming from. I've used a manual trigger for now so I can get the request working, then I'll change back to my outlook connector

**Power Automate Flow Error**

[image]

**Power Automate Flow Error pt2**

[image]

**HTTP request JSON**

[image]

I have tried removing the bot altogether from my Azure tenant, I've changed tenants and accounts. I have a tunnelling solution called Ngrok that opens my localhost to the internet, I've created a new account within Ngrok along with a new tunnel. I've changed all the configuration within my bot to match new app registrations. I'm looking for some guidance if I've missed anything in my configuration of my flow in Power Automate. Previously mentioned, the bot is up and running fine so I don't believe it's anything to do with the bot, could be certain permissions? Not sure.